# How to get daily active users considering previous subscription days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL to make some data analysis on subscribers and I would like to sort out daily active subscribers since the service launch.
i have a subscription table like below

```
id | subscriptiondate | unsubscriptiondate
---|------------------|--------------------
1  | 2020-02-12       | null
---|------------------|--------------------
2  | 2020-03-20       | 2020-04-01
---|------------------|--------------------
3  | 2020-03-10       | null
---|------------------|--------------------
4  |2020-04-02        | null
```

and i expect a result like:

```
date       | active_user
-----------|---------------------------
2020-02-12 | 1
-----------|------------------
2020-03-10 | 2
-----------|------------------
2020-03-20 | 3
-----------|------------------
2020-04-02 | 3
```

A subscriber opted out the 2020-04-01, that is why we have 3 active subscribers the 2020-04-02.

here is my SQL script, someone could check and assist me to achieve my goal?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(distinct is) AS active_user,
    date(subscriptiondate) as day
FROM
    subscriptions
WHERE
        subscriptiondate in (select subscriptiondate  from subscriptions where subscriptiondate <=date(subscriptiondate))
    AND (unsubscriptiondate is NULL or unsubscriptiondate>date(subscriptiondate))
GROUP BY
    day
ORDER BY day ASC*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "unpivot" the table and aggregate with a cumulative sum:

```
select date, sum(inc) as change_on_date,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by date) as active_on_day
from ((select subscriptiondate as date, 1 as inc from subscriptions
      ) union all
      (select unsubscriptiondate, -1 from subscriptions
      )
     ) s
group by date;
```